# How to parse json in logstash /grok from ansible_results

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have below messages from `ansible_results` which i'm trying to parse, what basically i need is to cut the down the field after `"msg":` from the below messages.

### Log sample:

```
2019-05-07 07:56:06,374 p=7743 u=root |  fatal: [xxxxx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The system may not be mirrored  according to the xxxx default mirror policy."}
2019-05-07 07:56:06,402 python-logstash-logger TASK FAILED | fail | HOST | xxxxxxx | RESULT | {"changed": false, "msg": "The system may not be mirrored  according to the xxx default mirror policy."}
```

I'm trying follows but not getting idea to accomplish this:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} p=%{INT:process} u=%{USER:user}|%{SPACE}falal:%{SPACE}%{WORD:fatal}%{SPACE}%{UNIXPATH: FAILED*?}
```

### Desired:

Segregated `msg` and `last message body` into two different fields..

```
msg    The system may not be mirrored  according to the xxxx default mirror policy.
```

Any expertise help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you only want the message, you might use `"msg": "%{GREEDYDATA:msg}"\}$`: with your examples you'll get `The system may not be mirrored  according to the xxxx default mirror policy.`

Comment: @baudsp, thnx for the answer, however i need completed log to be filtered.

Comment: Could you add what values from the logs you are interested in? It's easier to built the pattern with this info.

Comment: @baudsp, i would like `timestamp`, `process ID` `User` and then failed code fatal: `[hostname]` and failure code ie `FAILED!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've got two very different log type, I used two different grok pattern:

```
grok{
 match => [
   "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}.*p=%{INT:process} u=%{USER:user}.*%{WORD:result}! =>.*"msg": "%{GREEDYDATA:msg}"\}$",
   "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time}.*\|.*\|%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Host}%{SPACE}\|.*\|.*\|.*"msg": "%{GREEDYDATA:msg}"\}$
 ]
}
```

The first pattern with the first log line:

```
process     7743
result  FAILED
msg     The·system·may·not·be·mirrored··according·to·the·xxxx·default·mirror·policy.
time    2019-05-07·07:56:06,374
user    root
```

The second pattern with the second log line:

```
time    2019-05-07·07:56:06,402
Host    HOST·
msg     The·system·may·not·be·mirrored··according·to·the·xxx·default·mirror·policy.
```

Comment: Thanks @baudsp .. looks Great.